# What are the easiest wings to obtain?

Tags: terraria

I am looking to just trying out some wings. What is the easiest pair to obtain? Can any be achieved pre-hardmode?

Comment: Since wings require souls you can't get them pre hardmode.

Comment: Hot wings. You can pick em up just about anywhere. Getting them down, though, is another matter altogether.

Comment: I prefer buffalo wings.  Though it's so hard to make buffalos drop them.

Comment: Personally, I prefer schwings. Schaaaaaa- *wing*.

Comment: Sorting the wiki list by possible height gives a pretty good indicator of what to start with.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

**You cannot obtain wings before hardmode** (legitimately anyway). All of them require Souls of Flight from Wyverns, except the Leaf Wings and the Jetpack, which can be bought from NPCs, but only in Hardmode.

The easiest depends on your situation. Crafted wings:

- Angel/Demon Wings

  - Soul of Night/Light x25
  - Soul of Flight x20
- Fairy Wings

  - Soul of Flight x20
  - Pixie Dust x100 (really easy to get from Hallow, guaranteed drop)
- Harpy Wings

  - Soul of Flight x20
  - Giant Harpy Feather (might drop while killing the Wyvern for Souls of Flight)

From NPCs:

- Jetpack

  - 40 Gold, bought from Steampunker during a waxing moon (NPC requires defeating one Hardmode Mechanical boss to spawn)
- Leaf Wings

  - 1 Platinum, bought from Witch Doctor at night (must be living in a jungle biome in Hardmode)
- Fin Wings

  - 1% chance reward after 10th quest from the Angler, but only in Hardmode

The Terraria wiki has a [full list of Wings](http://terraria.gamepedia.com/Wings). In general, the better the wings, the more difficult it is to find the materials to craft the wings.

Comment: @Kotekzot that's incorrect; the requirement for the Witch Doctor moving in is to defeat the Queen Bee (and have an empty home of course).  He only sells some of his gear once you get the Pygmy staff.  The requirement for the wings to be on sale is "home in a jungle biome, and night time".

Comment: [Sour](http://terraria.gamepedia.com/Wings)[ces](http://terraria.gamepedia.com/Leaf_Wings)

Comment: @peacedog Does that mean that I can get the Leaf Wings before Hardmode, assuming I've defeated the Queen Bee, moved the Witch Doctor's house to the Jungle, and visited at night? Nevermind, checked the wiki, it says Hardmode required, as well.

Comment: @EtherDragon I inadvertantly left that out, sorry.  Yes, hardmode.

Comment: Later versions of Terraria made the ice/frost wings easier to get.

Answer (score 7):

No, none can be made pre-hardmode.

The easiest to obtain depends on what you consider easy.

- [Leaf Wings](http://terraria.gamepedia.com/Leaf_Wings) can be bought from the [Witch Doctor](http://terraria.gamepedia.com/Witch_Doctor) at night after you move him into the Jungle in hardmode.

  - 1 platinum (100 gold), but require no special materials
- [Angel/Demon Wings](http://terraria.gamepedia.com/Angel_Wings) use the most common materials. These are easier if you can't get the money for Leaf Wings

  - 25 Souls of Light/Night
  - 25 Souls of Flight
  - 10 Feathers
- While trying to get Feathers for the Angel/Demon Wings, you may find the rare drop Giant Harpy Feather.  If you happen to find this, you can make [Harpy Wings](http://terraria.gamepedia.com/Harpy_Wings) for fewer souls.

  - 1 Giant Harpy Feather
  - 20 Souls of Flight

So basically, you're choosing between spending your hard earned money, and fighting hardmode enemies.  If you can't kill hardmode enemies, go for the Leaf Wings.  If you can, go for the Angel/Demon Wings and hope you get the materials for Harpy Wings.

Answer (score 1):

By the time you can get wings they are all about the same difficulty to obtain since none really require anything extraordinary but I would say the [Harpy Wings](http://terraria.gamepedia.com/Harpy_Wings) are the easiest to obtain.

You need 20 [Souls of Flight](http://terraria.gamepedia.com/Soul_of_Flight) and a [Giant Harpy Feather](http://terraria.gamepedia.com/Giant_Harpy_Feather) (not a regular feather). Since you get Souls of Flight from [Wyvern](http://terraria.gamepedia.com/Wyvern) you are probably fighting [Harpies](http://terraria.gamepedia.com/Harpies) as well and it is likely they would have dropped a Giant Harpy Feather while you were up there anyway. So In the process of getting the Souls of Flight you probably have all of the ingredients by the time you have enough Souls of Flight, while almost all of the rest need either one more type of Soul that you can't get in the sky or need a rare item from a different area.

[List of all of the Wings in the game](http://terraria.gamepedia.com/Wings). Some can be bought.

Comment: Lots of wings aren't even available before beating certain bosses.

Answer (score -1):

Well you can get the flame wing but you need to go to the underworld